# How to change CSS background from different .asxc file?

Tags: css, asp.net, ascx

So the master file has a CSS file which defines the background

```
body{background-image:url(../background.jpg);}
```

Then I have an `aspx` file, with several `ascx` files. I want to change the background image directory (changing the image) depending on which `ascx` page is loaded. Any suggestions or guidance would be helpful. I simply can't wrap my head around it.

Edit:

So thanks to below, I now have some containers, but I'm not sure how I declare what container is to be used on what ascx load. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the body use a container inside of body using

```
<body>
<div id="container-home">
</div>
</body>


body
{
    margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
}
#container-home
{
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
   background-image:url(../background.jpg);
}

#container-otherpage
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
   background-image:url(../background.jpg);
}
```

Comment: ok great thanks, my next question is how do I tell it to use those containers depending on the ascx that is running?